# Oblique vs. Orthogonal Rotation for EFA

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, factor-rotation, rotation

Will orthogonal relationships show up when using Oblique rotation?

Based on the articles I have read on EFA rotation my understanding is that although oblique rotation procedures might be expected to be superior to orthogonal rotation procedures on theoretical grounds, that superiority has yet to be demonstrated empirically.

**References**

[Bandalos, D. L., & Boehm-Kaufman, M. R. (2009)](http://psycnet.apa.org/record/2008-09949-003). Four common misconceptions in exploratory factor analysis. In C. E. Lance, & R. J. Vandenberg (Eds.), *Statistical and methodological myths and legends: Doctrine, verity and fable in the organizational and social sciences* (pp. 61-88). New York, NY: Routledge.

Tinsley, H. E., & Tinsley, D. J. (1987). Uses of factor analysis in counseling psychology research. J*ournal of Counseling Psychology*, *34*(4), 414-424.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Orthogonal rotations are special cases of oblique rotations, so yes, they can show up.

(Can you provide better links to your articles?)

Edit: I don't think that the Bandalos and Boehn-Haufman says what you say it said. E.g. the end of that section of the chapter says [if you have done both orthogonal and oblique rotations] "the results from the oblique rotation are probably the best representation."

Comment: I tracked down the references and updated the OP. Letting you know because I was not sure if you were just pointing out that they would be helpful to other readers, or whether you wanted them to inform your response.

Comment: Thanks - I was interested in them. (I have the Lance and Vandenberg book - I'll take a look.)

Comment: A random follow-up, since you have the Lance & Vandenberg book: is it worth owning? I skimmed the table of contents while looking it up and it seemed like it could be a helpful resource, but I wasn't sure of the quality of chapters.

Comment: I haven't read the whole thing (and I haven't skimmed most of the chapters for years) but some of them are good. I often used to find myself citing the Chan chapter ("So why ask me?") when defending self-report data.

Comment: Thanks for the updates to the post. I provided a link for the Bandalos & Boehm-Kaufman (2009) article.

Comment: I like both Statistical and Methodological Myths and Urban Legends books by Lance and Vandenberg. I've also have had both as professors in grad school and enjoyed their classes.